# How to disable animations on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

I have tried using media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .animated {
        /*CSS transitions*/
        -o-transition-property: none !important;
        -moz-transition-property: none !important;
        -ms-transition-property: none !important;
        -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
        transition-property: none !important;
        /*CSS transforms*/
        -o-transform: none !important;
        -moz-transform: none !important;
        -ms-transform: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: none !important;
        transform: none !important;
        /*CSS animations*/
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        -moz-animation: none !important;
        -o-animation: none !important;
        -ms-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
    }
}
```

Also tried some css with javascript browser detector, but it still doesn't disable the animations.

```
.noanimated {
-webkit-animation-duration: none;
animation-duration: none;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-fill-mode: none;
}

Javascript

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
{
    $('body').addClass('noanimated'); // to remove transition
}
```

Not really sure what else to try.  I'm using Waypoints.css/Js as well with Animate.css if that helps.  Any info and feedback would be greatly appreciated guys. Thanks!

Here's my GitHub Repo https://github.com/Alex-Carver/NaiaFinal

Website: http://naia.ca/salmon/

Comment: Try `animation:initial` or pause it: `animation-play-state: paused`

Comment: Nvm I had the wrong class I was calling out in css. added .os-animation in the media query.  So there is no more animation, but when I scroll down the content still pops up instead of being displayed right away.  Any idea on how to change this?

Comment: Not enough info. My best guess is that it's related to `:none` which I think is invalid for animation and transition shorthand. Using !important on that isn't making it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yea I know !important really is never the right fix, but for now it works.  As for my other question I really don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Thanks though! I appreciate the help.